# best way to load balance dual esxi

Tags: vmware-esxi, load-balancing, high-availability

Im hosting a few websites on a single ESXi box that runs Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7. Now I would like to make sure that if the host goes down, the websites will still be live, so I've ordered a 2nd ESXi 5.1 box from LeaseWeb.

Both servers are free ESXi versions, they only have 1 nic, are not on a private network and don't have access to shared storage. What would be the best way to make sure when one machine goes down, the website are still reachable?

I could spin up a vm with ha proxy, but I'd need to load balance them too; what would be the best way to do that?

So, in summary; 2 stand-alone ESXi 5.1 boxes; what's the best way to utilise them to handle one of the two boxes failing?

Thanks,

Nick.

Comment: Seems to me that instead of monkeying with an ESXi server from leaseweb you should just get a Win2k8 VM from them.  That VM won't go down since it's on their redundant everything cluster.  For your needs you seem to not gain anything by running your own ESXi.

Comment: @RealityExtractor +1 This is the right solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Most people running multiple ESXi hosts would do so using the native high-availability features (HA) and possibly shared storage. Yours is a unique or uncommon case.

I think clustered load balancers (one per host) is one option. Another may be a cloud-based load balancer that factors availability as an attribute. Finally, maybe something as simple as DNS would work here.

Comment: yeah, the thing I could come up with myself would be dual A records pointing to two ha proxy instances. Regarding the HA features; I'm not sure they are possible for me since I use the free ESXi and have no shared storage available.

Comment: Since when can you run HA services without shared storage?

Comment: @3molo - You can't.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into StarWind iSCSI SAN free edition. If your VM can live on a vhd of 128GB or less then you can use this for HA.

http://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-free